# Convert bytes to XML legal text

Tags: xml, vb.net, byte

I have to store the bytes of a image file inside of an XML file that is read by another program... The problem is, if I inject it as just plain bytes, the end-program has an error (presumably because it contains non-legal XML characters).  How can I convert bytes into something that XML can legally read?  I really have no other options at this point.  I have to inject the image file as bytes (specifically a .bmp file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) the byte data to [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and embed that.